# how to develop web hook for google ad lead form in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webhooks, google-ads-api

I want to develop a webhook for adding leads automatically from google lead form into CRM. Google can call a webhook url to submit such leads.

Refer to the link:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/webhook/docs/overview

This link at microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/ have mentioned several nuget packages to build webhook receiver but none for google lead form.

Can any one help me to identify how can I build such webhook that can be called through google to add lead automatically into CRM.

TIA.

Comment: "Webhook" is a general term for anything that can accept an HTTP request. If you can create an API, you can call it a webhook as long as it conforms the requirements of the caller.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a webserver running at a publicly available host and capable of processing data from Google Ads servers in a format specified in [Ads docs.](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/webhook/docs/overview) 
Consider you have some server set up and running at youdomain.com/leads. When you create a lead ad you add that URL as a 'webhook' and Google sends an HTTP POST request to that URL each time a form is submitted with form data as a payload.
Here's an example of a sample ASP.NET server that could handle such requests https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api